# Create multidimensional associative array from form inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

What would be the best way to create a multidimensional associative array from form inputs?

The form looks like this:

```
<div id="items">
    <h4>Engraving Text</h4>
    <div class="item" data-position="1">
        <h4 id="engraving-item">Item 1</h4>
        <label>Engraving Line 1: </label>
        <input type="text" class="engraving-input engraving-line1" name="trophy" id="item1-line1">
        <br />
        <label>Engraving Line 2: </label>
        <input type="text" class="engraving-input engraving-line2" name="trophy" id="item1-line2">
        <br />
        <label>Engraving Line 3: </label>
        <input type="text" class="engraving-input engraving-line3" name="trophy" id="item1-line3">
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
```

If the user enters that they want multiple items - additional inputs are dynamically added to the form using these first 3 as a template.

I'm looking to create this sort of array (for example if the user added 2 items):

```
var myArray =   {
            item1 :
                [
                    {
                        engraving-line1 : "user entered data",
                        engraving-line2 : "more user data",
                        engraving-line3 : "yep, more data"
                    }
                ],
            item2 :
                [
                    {
                        engraving-line1 : "user entered data",
                        engraving-line2 : "more user data",
                        engraving-line3 : "yep, more data"
                    }
                ]
          };
```

I had written this but I think I am headed in the wrong direction with it or at the very least - writing it poorly.

```
var totalItems = $("#quantity_wanted").val();

jsonObj = [];

i=1;

while (i < totalItems){
items = {};
$('.item[data-position="'+i+'"] :input').each(function(){
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    var engraving = $(this).val();
    item = {}
    item ["name"] = name;
    item ["engraving"] = engraving;
    items.push(item);       
});

jsonObj.push(items) 
i++;    
}
```

Just looking for help writing the javascript that will help me to iterate through the inputs on the screen and push them into a multidimentional associative array like the one I listed.

Comment: `id` of an `html` element should be unique

Comment: udpated.  Thank you!

Comment: Which part isn't working?

Comment: `items = {};` should be `items = [];`. The `object` prototype doesn't have a `push` method. And make sure you declare your variables properly: `var items = [];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code could be much simplified.

1. `data-position` attribute in jquery selector doesn't make sense
   since you don't actually use its value. You just need to select all
   input group containers by their shared class (`.item`), then, for
   each container, select all descendant inputs.
2. Your code building `item` element is redundant. You can use inline
   object literal/initializer (`{...}`) instead.

Furthermore, as @Andy noted, `items` array should be initialized by array literal (`[]`), not object (`{}`).

So the code should look like this:

```
var jsonObj = [];
$('div.item').each(function(){
    var items = [];
    $(this).find('input').each(function() {
        items.push({
            name: $(this).attr("name"), engraving: $(this).val()
        });       
    });
    jsonObj.push(items) 
});
```

Comment: A much more beautiful way to be sure.  This works a treat. On my first input I have a button to 'repeat' the user input over all the following inputs on the page (so if they wanted to copy the same line 1 to each item they can) - is there a nice way to write it to avoid putting those inputs in the array (although I guess it doesn't really matter)?